# What does the dollar sign mean in the get_json_object spark utility function?

Tags: json, apache-spark, complex-data-types

I am following [this](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/complex-nested-structured.html) documentation to handle nested data in spark. However, it is not clear to me, why the structure of the path to the target object starts with a dollar sign symbol. For example, `get_json_object(col("jsonColumn"), "$.path.to.data")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the advantage of using $"col" over "col" in spark data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56305811/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-col-over-col-in-spark-data-frames)

Comment: @thebluephantom I think he's mentioning about `"$.path.to.data"` object selector

Answer (score 1):

It is just how the api works, that simple. Sometimes col(..., $. Depends on the api.